# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException while building WAR file

Tags: intellij-idea, war, artifact

I am getting this error on Intellij IDEA 2018.3.1 Ultimate Edition while building WEB application archive(WAR) file. I wrote build path wrong first as in below. There is space character at index 2.
Wrong Path: "D: \my_folder\XXX.war"

**Error:Artifact 'XXX': java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 2: D: \my_folder\XXX.war**

I fixed the path as "D:\my_folder\XXX.war" and try to build artifact, but it still gives to me same error.
I tried with different WAR name (YYY.war) in fixed path, builded. After that, I changed path as **C:**\folder and I wrote same WAR name (XXX.war) but it gave to me same error with old path although the disk changes.

Error:Artifact 'XXX': java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 2: **D:** \my_folder\XXX.war

I can't use "XXX" as artifact name in no way.

What else I tried:

- Intellij IDEA restarted.
- Artifacts deleted and created again.
- Invalidate Caches / Restart.

[image: artifact_creation]

Comment: As a workaround, if you delete (or rename) your \.idea folder, does it start successfully?

Comment: @Kootli I deleted .idea folder and made again all configurations but it gave to me same error. Should I restart the PC?

Answer (score 1):

**Build > Rebuild Project** solved the problem. After that, WAR file builded successfully.